# Posting Mongo ObjectId from Postman

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, json.net, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDb.Driver in C# and I have a model like this:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
}
```

`UserId` is of type `ObjectId` from another collection.

In postman I'm trying to POST a request with body:

```
{
    "userId": "5cc082d130b097e86665309d"
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
{
    "userId": [
        "Error converting value \"5cc082d130b097e86665309d\" to type 'MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId'. Path 'userId', line 2, position 39."
    ]
}
```

How can I post `ObjectId`, or do I need some attribute on the property of this type?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this exception because **Newtonsoft.Json** is not able to convert string you're sending into MongoDB's `ObjectId`. To fix that you can implement your own [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) and run the conversion using `ObjectId.Parse()`:

```
public class StringToObjectId : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(ObjectId);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return ObjectId.Parse(token.ToObject<string>());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you can decorate your property with [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) attribute:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToObjectId))]
    public ObjectId UserId { get; set; }
}
```